# C# programmatically Compile Form at Runtime without console

Tags: c#, .net, forms, runtime, compilation

Why compiling this create an exe which :

- open a console
- launch the form ?

What can be done for the **runtime compiled form open alone**, **without console** ?

```
//LIST OF USING
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;



 //CODE TO COMPILE
 string oSource = @"
  using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System;
 namespace fTest
  {
    public static class Program
    {
     public static void Main()
     {
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new MyForm());
     }
    }
  public  class MyForm:Form
    {
     public  MyForm()
     {
      this.Text=""Generated exe"";
     MessageBox.Show(""Generated exe says H3110 W0r1d"");
     }
    }    
  }";
  string compiledOutput="Generated.exe";

 //COMPILATION WORK
 String [] referenceAssemblies={"System.dll","System.Drawing.dll","System.Windows.Forms.dll"};

 CodeDomProvider _CodeCompiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters _CompilerParameters =
  new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters(referenceAssemblies,"");

 _CompilerParameters.OutputAssembly = compiledOutput;
 _CompilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
 _CompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
 _CompilerParameters.WarningLevel = 3;
 _CompilerParameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;
 _CompilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/optimize /target:winexe";//!! HERE IS THE SOLUTION !!

 string _Errors = null;
 try
 {
  // Invoke compilation
  CompilerResults _CompilerResults = null;
  _CompilerResults = _CodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(_CompilerParameters, oSource);                                                

  if (_CompilerResults.Errors.Count > 0)
  {
   // Return compilation errors
   _Errors = "";
   foreach (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError CompErr in _CompilerResults.Errors)
   {
    _Errors += "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
    ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
    ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";\r\n\r\n";
   }
  }
 }catch (Exception _Exception)
 {
  // Error occurred when trying to compile the code
  _Errors = _Exception.Message;
 } 



  //AFTER WORK
 if (_Errors==null)
 {
  // lets run the program
  MessageBox.Show(compiledOutput+" Compiled !");
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(compiledOutput); 
 }else
 {
  MessageBox.Show("Error occurred during compilation : \r\n" + _Errors);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `csc` compiles console applications. You need to add `/target:winexe` to compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding "target:winexe" to the command line parameters?